# TreeSet raises ClassCastException?

Tags: java

I have the following TreeSet:

```
private TreeSet<BWidgetObject<D>> entries = new TreeSet<BWidgetObject<D>>();
```

where:

```
public interface BWidgetObject<D> extends Comparable<D> {
}
```

I created:

```
public class BItemDtoWidgetObject implements BWidgetObject<ItemDto> {
  private ItemDto itemDto;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return itemDto.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(ItemDto o) {
    return itemDto.compareTo(o);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    BItemDtoWidgetObject otherWidgetObject;
    if (obj instanceof BItemDtoWidgetObject) {
      otherWidgetObject = (BItemDtoWidgetObject)obj;
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalStateException("BItemDtoWidgetObject - equals obj is not instance of BItemDtoWidgetObject");
    }
    boolean result = this.itemDto.equals(otherWidgetObject.getDto());    
    return result;
  }
}
```

In my main program I used the TreeSee `entries` from above insert and remove `BItemDtoWidgetObject`.

```
public void instert(BItemDtoWidgetObject w) {
  entries.add(w);
}

public boolean remove(BItemDtoWidgetObject w) {
  return entries.remove(w);
}
```

Insert operation works fine, but when I execute `remove` like this:

```
BItemDtoWidgetObject w = // some instance
boolean isRemoved = remove(w);
```

then I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
    at Unknown.fillInStackTrace_0_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.Throwable_1_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.Exception_1_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.RuntimeException_1_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.ClassCastException_1_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.dynamicCast_0_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.compareTo_3_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.compareTo_Ljava_lang_Object__I__devirtual$_0_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.compare_48_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.compare_49_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.removeWithState_0_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.remove_222_g$(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.remove_226_g$(Unknown Source)
```

I do not understand why I get a `ClassCastException`. I implemented hashCode, equals, and compareTo so everything should be fine when the item is removed.

**Why does the entry TreeSet raises a ClassCastException?**

Edit: `ItemDto` is:

```
class ItemDto {
 String id;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode()));
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `BWidgetObject<D>` extend `Comparable<BWidgetObject<D>>` if you want to compare it to other BWidgetObjects?

Comment: @confile can you post your `ItemDto` class?

Comment: Unrelated, but `equals` should not throw `IllegalStateException`. In that case it should return false (since it is not equals).

Comment: Read [the `TreeSet` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). Search the page for `ClassCastException` if you must.

Comment: In addition to Steve Kuo's comment: *If* an exception is thrown because something is wrong with a argument, `IllegalArgumentException` would be more appropriate than `IllegalStateException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TreeSet` keeps the elements that you put into it in sorted order.

To be able to determine what the right order is, it needs to be able to compare elements.

Therefore `TreeSet` requires either that your class `BWidgetObject` implements interface `Comparable`, or that you use the constructor of `TreeSet` that takes a `Comparator`.

Note: `BWidgetObject<D>` should extend `Comparable<BWidgetObject<D>>`, not `Comparable<D>`:

```
public interface BWidgetObject<D> extends Comparable<BWidgetObject<D>> {
}

public class BItemDtoWidgetObject implements BWidgetObject<ItemDto> {
    // ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BWidgetObject<ItemDto> other) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compareTo(ItemDto o) {
    return itemDto.compareTo(o);
}
```

should be

```
public int compareTo(BItemDtoWidgetObject o) {
    return itemDto.compareTo(o.itemDto);
}
```

The comparable interface takes an instance of the same type. Not your wrapped type.